# How to apply recursive aggregation in the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using mongodb for storing the information into the database. But I don't know that will I use pipe for same collection from which I'm getting the data? Let me explain it with an example:

I have some documents in a collection "inventory" example:-

```
{
  "_id" : 1, 
  "review" : "this is a review", 
  "bot_id" : 1 
}
{
"_id" : 2,
"review" : "this is a second review",
"type" : "reply",
"reply_to" : 1,
"bot_id" : 1
}
{
"_id" : 3,
"review" : "this is a third review",
"type" : "reply",
"reply_to" : 1,
"bot_id" : 1
}
{
  "_id" : 4, 
  "review" : "this is a another review", 
  "bot_id" : 2
}
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "review" : "this is a fifth review",
  "type" : "reply",
  "reply_to" : 2,
  "bot_id" : 1
}
```

I have to fetch the result like the `_id` of the first document is attached to the `reply_to` field of the second, third document and the match will be on the `bot_id` field the first document is like a parent and then the second and the third will act a the children of the first and then with `_id:4` it is also a parent. Can anyone explain what query should I have to execute that I get my desired output?

Output I want:-

```
{
  "_id" : 1, 
  "review" : "this is a review", 
  "bot_id" : 1
  "replies":[
     {
       "_id" : 2,
       "review" : "this is a second review",
       "type" : "reply",
       "reply_to" : 1,
       "bot_id" : 1,
       "replies":[
            {
               "_id" : 5,
               "review" : "this is a fifth review",
               "type" : "reply",
               "reply_to" : 2,
               "bot_id" : 1,
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id" : 3,
        "review" : "this is a third review",
        "type" : "reply",
        "reply_to" : 1,
        "bot_id" : 1
       }
   ]
}
{
  "_id" : 4, 
  "review" : "this is a another review", 
  "bot_id" : 2
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exact output of your required result of above documents.

Comment: @krishnaPrasad see the output what I want

Comment: @krishnaPrasad please can you tell me what i have to do?

Comment: Have a look at official documentation of  `$graphLookup (aggregation)`
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#graphlookup-aggregation , focus on examples.

Comment: @krishnaPrasad it does not satisfied my result can you please tell it with `$group`

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with one level of **reply_to** by using the `$graphLookup` **aggregation** as below:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{
    $match: {"reply_to" : null }
}, 
{
    $graphLookup: { 
        from: "collectionName", 
        startWith:"$_id" , 
        connectFromField: "_id", 
        connectToField: "reply_to", 
        as: "replies"
    }    
}]).pretty()
```

Output as:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "review" : "this is a review",
    "bot_id" : 1,
    "replies" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "review" : "this is a third review",
            "type" : "reply",
            "reply_to" : 1,
            "bot_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "review" : "this is a fifth review",
            "type" : "reply",
            "reply_to" : 2,
            "bot_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "review" : "this is a second review",
            "type" : "reply",
            "reply_to" : 1,
            "bot_id" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "review" : "this is a another review",
    "bot_id" : 2,
    "replies" : [ ]
}
```

Further level of Hierarchy, you have checkout the official documents of [graph lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup)